# Python - What is the logic behind + function(i) +

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In the following block of codes:

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
```

I understand that the code will run 5 times where i = 0 to 4.

However, I don't understand the logic behind the + operators added before and after the str() function.

How can this + function() + applied to other scenarios?

Comment: string concatenation

Comment: Because `function()` always *evaluates to a value first*, and then the operators are applied. `str` will either return a `str` or throw an error. The `+` operator between strings *concatenates*. So try `"hello" + " world"`

Answer (score 2):

`str(i)` is the string representation of `i`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str):

> Return a str version of object.

If `a`, `b` and `c` are strings, then `a + b + c` is the string resulting of their concatenation.

Therefore, with `i` being an `int` between `0` and `4`, say `3`, `'Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')'` is the folowing string:

```
'Jimmy Five Times (3)'
```

Comment: I would add that this isn't the best way to format a string in python. This is a java-style bad way of writing it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre By the way, what do you think about Python 3.6's formatting? I personnally don't like it much, except for short strings, I find it rather dirty...

Comment: the `f` strings? well, I dunno, we don't have this version at work. Stops at 3.5, with 2.7 compatibility required. So it'll take a while before I dig into it. But I adopted `str.format` all right and it's powerful enough.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `+` is used for string contate.
i.e:

```
data1 = "Hello"
data2 = "World"

print(data1+data2)
```

The output will be :

```
HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a function that returns a string representation of `i`, so:

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
# => 'Jimmy Fine Times (0)'
# => 'Jimmy Fine Times (1)'
# => 'Jimmy Fine Times (...
```

Calling a function that returns a string within a string concatenation `'A' + func() + 'B'`, will just use replace the function call with the string returned by the function (if no error or exceptions were raised), example:

```
def getName():
  name=input('Enter name: ')
  return name

print('Hello '+getName()+', Welcome to StackOverflow.')

#In: Enter name:  Jack
#Out: Hello Jack, Welcome to StackOverflow.
```